# how do I find location of packages

Tags: apt, php, software-sources

I am trying to install several things on my machine.
For example php-pear.
I need to put to location of the repository in sources.list
How can I locate it?

Answer (score 1):

The `php-pear` package is in the official Ubuntu archive.

Comment: I have maveric which is old, what should I use to get the newest version

Comment: You should upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu which will receive security updates, and have a newer version of the package available. Ubuntu 10.10 is End of Life.

Comment: How do I do it without getting that horrible Unity GUI?

Comment: You can choose whatever GUI to use, that you want. Just install a different one and use it instead.